# How can we test the return type of method by using sinon.spy?

Tags: reactjs, sinon, sinon-chai

We are using the sinon to test our api call in reactjs application Like this:-

```
import * as Actions from 'routes/actions/Actions';
const requestAction = {
  RequestShell() { Actions.request(); },
};
 describe('testing for Actions', () => {
  it('check whether request() method call is happening properly or not', () => {
   const requestData = sinon.spy(requestAction, 'RequestShell');
   requestAction.RequestShell();
   sinon.assert.calledOnce(requestData);
   requestData.restore();
 });
```

Now I need to compare if `Actions.request()` return type is Json object or not. How can I test the return type of the action by using **sinon**? Please assist me.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

**JS**

```
 it('check whether request() method call is happening properly or not', () => {
    const requestData = sinon.spy(requestAction, 'RequestShell');
    requestAction.RequestShell();
    assert(requestData.calledOnce);
    requestAction.RequestShell.restore();
  });
```

refer this link[sinon spies](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.1.0/spies/)